# How many equations are there to calculate distance?

Tags: kinematics

I am an app developer and I am trying to build a physics app to calculate distance based on the quantities the user gives. for example if the user gives initial speed, time and acceleration, using Newton's 2nd equation, my program can calculate distance. So for example if I have six basic formulas which are:-

$$s = \frac{d}{t}$$
$$d = ut + \frac{at^2}{2}$$
$$v^2 - u^2 = 2ad$$
$$s = \frac{u+v}{2}$$
$$a = \frac{v-u}{t}$$
$$v = u + at$$

where:

$s$ = average speed

$d$ = distance

$u$ and $v$ are initial and final speed

$t$ = time

$a$ = acceleration

Out of these, are there a definite number of equations I can derive to calculate distance if some combinations of quantities are given or will it be way too many as I might have some more equations.

Comment: I cannot recommend strongly enough that you contract an actual physicist before attempting to write such an app.  The fact that you don't appear to realize that, e.g., the last 2 equations you wrote are the same equation, suggests you need a lot of help in both physics and math.  Take a look, for example, at TK!Solver, an app which knows how to invert equations depending on the inputs the user supplies.

Comment: Also, be really careful. s in your first equation is speed, but is then used to represent distance in all the others (and v for speed)...

Comment: Yeah the last two equations are the same same but the first is in terms of acceleration the next in final velocity. My question is, how many such equations can be formed? Is there a definite number of equations in terms of distance or is it too large or infinite(though that's a little unlikely).Also  yeah I know s is average speed in first but to avoid confusion I took d as distance and s as average speed which leaves u and v for initial and final.

Comment: Here's what you do, start by assuming you're given everything but d and determine the easiest way to find d. Then remove one variable from your givens and find the easiest way to get d. Then replace that variable and remove a different one...... After going through all of the, next pick two values to remove from the givens. Continue in this fashion. If you can't find d, then you know to have the app tell the user it's unsolvable. Wash. Rinse. Repeat

Comment: Want it to be a better app? Go get someone from engineering physics. Someone who knows Lagrangian mechanics and how to approximate when something is unknown. Because there is really only one equation for getting the distance: $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot x_i}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_i}$ Then you solve that for anything you want

Comment: The equation that you use will be a bit dependent on the system of units that the user is using.  This will add some complexity to the app.

Comment: how about the mean square displacement MSD=diffusion coefficient * time so x=sqrt(D*time)

Answer (score 4):

Distance is calculated from one of the following direct integrals

1. Speed is known as a function of time

   $$x  = \int v(t)\,{\rm d} t $$
2. Acceleration is known as a function of time

   $$ x  = \iint a(t)\,{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}t $$
3. Speed is known as a function of distance

   $$ t  = \int \frac{1}{v(x)}\,{\rm d}x \; \Rightarrow \mbox{solve for $x$} $$
4. Acceleration is known as a function of speed

   $$ x  = \int \frac{v}{a(v)}\,{\rm d}v $$

For example, I am going to use both $a(t)=a(v)=g$ in (2) and (4) to demonstrate how you arrive at a particular equation for the given inputs:

$$ x = \iint g\,{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}t = \int g t \,{\rm d} t = v_0 t + \frac{1}{2} g t^2 $$
$$ x = \int \frac{v}{g} \,{\rm d}v =  \frac{1}{2 g} \left( v^2 - v_0^2 \right) $$

Here are some other examples:

- If we know $v(t) = 5 (1-\sin(\pi t))$, then from (1)

  $$ x = \int 5 (1-\sin(\pi t))\,{\rm d}t = \tfrac{5}{\pi} ( \cos(\pi t)-1) + 5 t $$
- If we know $a = -5 \sin(\pi t)$, then from (2)

  $$ x = -\iint 5 \sin(\pi t)\,{\rm d}t = \tfrac{5}{\pi^2} \sin(\pi t) $$
- If we know $v(x) = \sqrt{2 g (5-x)}$, then from (3)

  $$ t = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 g (5-x)}}\,{\rm d}x = \sqrt{ \frac{2 (5-x)}{g} } $$
  $$ x = 5 - \tfrac{1}{2} g t^2 $$
- If we know $a(v) = 10/v$, then from (4)

  $$ x = \int \frac{v}{ \tfrac{10}{v} }\,{\rm d}v = \tfrac{1}{30} v^3 $$

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you only want to find the distance whenever the acceleration is a constant value. If not, the suvat-equations

(U: initial velocity

V: final velocity

A: acceleration

T: time) no longer apply.

Furthermore, it is important to emphasise what is defined by 'distance'. The value that you are actually calculating is the displacement, i.e. the distance away from the starting point of the motion. This is not the same as the total distance travelled by the object throughout its motion. To calculate the total distance travelled, you would need to find all the points in time where the velocity falls to zero, then find the values of displacement between neighbouring points in time, including the start and endpoints of the motion. Then you would need to take the absolute value of each of those displacements, and then add the values to get the total distance travelled.

Anyways, to find the displacement, let us define the following variables:

$d=$ the displacement of the object from the starting point
$u=$ the velocity at the start of the motion
$v=$ the velocity at the end of the motion
$a=$ the acceleration of the object throughout the motion
$t_p=$ the time it takes between the start of the motion (duvat), and the end

If you derive from first principles, you will get two independent equations:
$$v = u + at_p$$
$$v^2 = u^2 + 2as$$

Therefore, we can obtain four equations with $d$ as the subject:
$$d = \frac{v^2-u^2}{2a}$$
$$d = ut_p + \frac{1}{2}at_p^2$$
$$d = vt_p - \frac{1}{2}at_p^2$$
$$d = \frac{1}{2}(u+v)t_p$$

There is one more aspect of this "the distance traveled in the t th second":

$d_{t^{th}}$

$= d_t - d_{t - 1}$

$= ut + \frac12 at^2 - u(t-1) - \frac12 a(t-1)^2$

$= ut + \frac12 at^2 - ut + u - \frac12 a(t-1)^2$

$= u + \frac12 a[t^2 - (t - 1)^2]$

$= u + \frac12 a(2t - 1)$

If, however, you want to find the displacement of an object that has an acceleration that changes over time, you will have to adopt a different approach, and this would involve having to input the velocity or acceleration of the object as a function of time, instead of a single value. An example of the input would be:

Velocity Function: [ $3t^2+2t-5$ ] metres per second
Duration: [ $10$ ] seconds

--Calculation--

Answer: Displacement: [ $1050$ ] metres

or

Acceleration Function: [ $6t+2$ ] metres per second squared
Initial Velocity: [ $315$ ] metres per second
Duration: [ $10$ ] seconds

--Calculation--

Answer: Displacement: [ $1050$ ] metres

I can post more on getting displacements when there is variable acceleration if that's what you're also looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> How many equations are there to calculate distance?

Depends what you consider a "distance equation". If I could write it in such form, then it may be just one ($\pm$) :

$$ \vec{r}(t) = \int_1\int_2\int_3...\int_n \vec{k}_n \space dt^n $$

Where

$\vec k_1 $ - speed, $\vec k_2 $ - acceleration, $\vec k_3 $ - [jolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)), $\vec k_4 $ - [jounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jounce), and ... so on up to infinity, because there is no theoretical limit on how much there can be "changes of changes" detected and/or produced.

Then, if you want **an exact** solution to that equation, you must integrate. For example integrating jounce, we get :

$$ {\vec {r}}={\vec {r}}_{0}+{\vec {v}}_{0}t+{\frac {1}{2}}{\vec {a}}_{0}t^{2}+{\frac {1}{6}}{\vec {\jmath }}_{0}t^{3}+{\frac {1}{24}}{\vec {s}}t^{4} $$

So as $n \rightarrow \infty $, solving exact case produces infinite amount of equation terms. Solution will be just one, but you will not be able to calculate the answer, because you will need to sum over infinite amount of terms. That's in theory.

Practically, it's enough for you to stop at jounce. Still in that case solving for $t$ in jounce equation is not a trivial task.
What I want to say from all this is that Physics is a very broad and evolving subject, so probably the best answer to your question is that there is no "final set of equations". Physics is about setting all required constraints and finding analytical solution to that constraints system. Sometimes to given constraints this is not possible at all. In this case we can try to find an answer using computational or simulation methods. Even then, they may produce sporadic or chaotic behavior.